# Non European flying to Germany to buy an expensive item. I am returning home through Switzerland, where should I request a tax refund?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, duty-free, tax-refunds, vat

I will be buying an expensive item in Germany, then after a few weeks I will visit Switzerland. A few days later I will take a direct flight home. How should I apply for my tax refund? Are there border agents on the border (of Basel) who can give me the refund? Does it have to be on the last leg of my trip (ie. flight home from Switzerland)?

Comment: Please note that the paperwork has to be done "properly". Check with the seller and ask if they familiar with this. For example we had a tax refund refused since the address on the Invoice was a German one (we had our son buy the item to avoid international shipping charges).

Comment: How are you travelling from Germany to Switzerland? By road, many of the border offices will have limited opening hours.

Comment: @jcaron by train, but I will be staying in Basel for a few days. I will make sure to check the times

Comment: Also note that Switzerland has an _import tax_, on top of VAT, which you also have to do paperwork for.

Comment: As @MatthieuM. notes, you will need to pay import duties in Switzerland, which will be refunded on exit. [More information here.](https://www.bazg.admin.ch/bazg/en/home/information-individuals/travel-and-purchases--allowances-and-duty-free-limit/transit-through-switzerland.html)

Comment: Note sure what the process is on trains from Germany to Basel. From France to Switzerland it happens either on board the train (if at all) in trains to Lausanne or Neuchâtel, while it happens in the station in Basel and Geneva (or at least it used to happen before Schengen, not quite sure nowadays). Don’t know what the situation is on the German side, though you probably want to get off at Bad Bhf rather than Basel SBB.

Comment: @StephanKolassa the deposit is not an import duty but security for the subsequent re-export of the goods.

Comment: @MatthieuM. For most goods, only VAT is due.  Additional import duties are payable on certain kinds of food as well as alcohol and tobacco (subject to certain exemptions).  Details are available at https://www.bazg.admin.ch/bazg/en/home/information-individuals/travel-and-purchases--allowances-and-duty-free-limit/importation-into-switzerland/duty-free-allowances--foodstuffs--alcohol-and-tobacco.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tax refund is available after the item is exported from the European Union, which happens when you take it to Switzerland.  You do not get the tax from border agents but from the seller of the item.  The agents merely stamp the export documentation to certify that the item was exported from the EU and that the VAT is therefore refundable.

Once you have that stamp, you have to return the documents to the seller, who can then refund the tax.  Since many tourists are not in a position to do this, there are companies that take care of it for you in exchange for a significant commission.

The German customs service has [a page detailing the process](https://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Leaving-Germany/Tax-free-shopping/tax-free-shopping_node.html).

There are customs inspection posts on the Swiss/German border.  You can find EU customs posts at https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/rd/rd_consultation_location.jsp

Comment: Note that the ones you want to stamp your form are the German agents, not the Swiss ones. Note also that the Swiss ones will often notice you stopped at the German offices and will ask why. At which point they can charge you local taxes (VAT and import duties). The fact that you are exiting the country shortly after further complicates things, not quite sure how you could claim back those local taxes (or if there’s a way to avoid paying those in the first place).

Comment: @jcaron . I see, I will make sure to take into account that the price may or may not include VAT

Comment: Anecdotal side note: A friend once told me that his father had some furniture shipped from Germany to his holiday home in Italy. While the father would always drive through Switzerland to get there, the shipping company decided to take a longer route through Austria, only to avoid having to deal with taxes...

Comment: @jcaron if the total value of imported goods is under 300 francs, there is no VAT due.